# Implement Protobuf net v2 with entity framework return data

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Can anybody point out what's wrong with my source code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using CCBProductionEntityModel;
using ConsoleDebug.NestleWebReference;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ConsoleDebug
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This is where I get data from and store into a list
            CCBProductionEntities et = new CCBProductionEntities();
            List<GetNestleData_Result> results = et.GetNestleData(5).ToList();

            List<GetNestleData_Result> responseResults;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, results);

                using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    responseResults = Serializer.Deserialize<List<GetNestleData_Result>>(responseStream);
                }
            }

            results = responseResults;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
            {
                var result = results.ElementAt(i);
                sb.Append(result.AssetId + "\t" + result.DeviceId + "\t" + result.InstanceNumber + "\t" + result.Speed + "\t" + result.Heading + "\t" + result.DriverId + "\t" + result.PositionAge + "\t" + result.VehicleRegistrationNum + "\t" + result.GSMAddress + "\t" + result.Odometer + "\t" + result.Latitude + "\t" + result.Longitude + "\t" + result.Altitude + "\t" + result.IgnitionState);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run, I got error message:
Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: CCBProductionEntityModel.GetNestleData_Result

I try to search everywhere for example source code, but kinda hard to find a good and clean one, is it I have to define somethings before using serializer? And How? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where is `GetNestleData_Result` defined? is this your own code? or did this come out of an EF code-generator? or...?

Basically, protobuf-net wants to work with types that declare a data contract that it can use for serialization. In particular, because the protobuf wife format does not include *member names* (but just field numbers instead), it needs a way of knowing that `1` === `Name`, etc. There are various ways of doing this. The simplest, if the type is your own code, is to add attributes - it will recognize a few patterns, for example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class GetNestleData_Result {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<Foo> SomeMoreValues {get;set;}

    // etc
}
```

or

```
[DataContract]
public class GetNestleData_Result {
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}

    [DataMember(Order=2)]
    public List<Foo> SomeMoreValues {get;set;}

    // etc
}
```

If you are using code-gen, sometimes the code-gen tool will happily add `DataContract`/`DataMember` (for WCF purposes); but if it doesn't, it isn't desirable to edit a generated file. In that case, there is also support for doing this in a `partial` class in a separate code file - which the compiler then stitches together for you:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoPartialMember(1, "SomeValue")]
[ProtoPartialMember(2, "SomeMoreValues")]
partial class GetNestleData_Result {}
```

If, however, the type is completely outside of your control, and does not include any attributes that it can use to determine order, you can also configure everything in code:

```
RuntimeTypeMode.Default.Add(typeof(GetNestleData_Result), false)
                       .Add("SomeValue", "SomeMoreValues");
```

which will do the same thing.

Once the serializer knows how your type should be configured, it should work.

Comment: I have 3 more concerns related protobuf though:

i. After i got the stream form of my objects, If I would like to consume to Web service, how I encode it so that the stream is consumable? XML Encode?

ii. I trying to send protobuf format data from console to Web service with additional compression again, is that neccessary?

iii. So I have to do this decoration  everytime to the "class" file in order for the protobuf serialization to work? No shortcut or cleaner code way?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marc, you are very fast response :)
I got it works by decorate the class generated from Entity Framework Model:

```
public partial class GetNestleData_Result
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Nullable<int> AssetId { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public long DeviceId { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Nullable<int> EventTime { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public Nullable<short> InstanceNumber { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public Nullable<short> Speed { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public Nullable<short> Heading { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public Nullable<int> DriverId { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(8)]
    public Nullable<short> PositionAge { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(9)]
    public string VehicleRegistrationNum { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(10)]
    public string GSMAddress { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(11)]
    public Nullable<int> Odometer { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(12)]
    public Nullable<int> Latitude { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(13)]
    public Nullable<short> Altitude { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(14)]
    public Nullable<int> Longitude { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(15)]
    public string IgnitionState { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: omg, deserialize not working again, I follow back same steps, a list of certain type returned with correct length but all zero/null values, any possible cause of this? Please help!